# Can the reduced product construction generate boolean-valued models?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, boolean-algebra

In model theory, the [reduced product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_product) construction contains a collection of structures or models, a set $I$ that indexes the collection, and a filter $U$ on $I$. [Ultraproducts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) are a special case of reduced products, where $U$ is an ultrafilter.

[Boolean-valued models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean-valued_model) are used primarily in connection with independence proofs in set theory, for example in Rosser's book *[Simplified Independence Proofs](http://books.google.com/books?id=7DNs5qgHTI0C&lpg=PP1&dq=simplified%20independence%20proofs&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)*. A boolean-valued model contains a boolean algebra $B$, and each sentence $S$ of the language $L$ is assigned an element of $B$ as a value. These differ from standard models in which either $S$ or $\sim S$ is satisfied at each model. Or one may say the standard models use a $2$-valued boolean algebra.

**Proposed construction:** Take the index set $I$ of a reduced product construction as a set of elements and give it the powerset boolean algebra $P(I)$. Each sentence $S$ of the language $L$ is assigned an element of $P(I)$, namely the set containing the indexes of the models at which it's satisfied. Use the filter $U$ to define the quotient algebra $P(I)/U$. Then each sentence $S$ of the language has a derived value in the quotient algebra. If the value assigned to $S$ is in the filter $U$ then $S$'s value in the quotient algebra will be the unit element, and the value of $\sim S$ will be zero element. If $U$ is an ultrafilter, every $S$ will be asssigned the unit or the zero, but otherwise some sentences will have other values. This generates boolean-valued models for the language $L$.

This is only an outline; many details are missing. But it appears to show how to use a reduced product to construct a boolean-valued model. Does anyone know if this will or won't work, or has been done already?

Comment: Mike: I'm not sure what you are trying to construct? Are you trying to construct a Boolean-valued model? Do you intend to use this for forcing related constructions, or in general?

Comment: @Asaf: yes, I'm trying to construct boolean-valued models. The reduced product construction is for first-order logic in general. The boolean-valued models for set theory are special-purpose. I'm thinking if we cross-breed the two we might find something useful, but I'm not sure what exactly. Forcing is not in my cross hairs at the moment ;-).

Comment: Mike: The idea seems reasonable, try searching it on MathSciNet (or Google Scholar if you can't use the former). If you find nothing, well.. this is a good exercise in verifying definitions. Sort of an extension of Los' theorem to Boolean-valued models.